Is $X\times \{0,1\}$ in the unreduced suspension contractible?
I am trying to prove that the unreduced suspension of a CW complex $X$ is a CW complex and I am using the idea of the relative CW complexes given here Suspension of a CW complex my idea (in terms of Allen Hatcher book) is that a relative CW complex is just like a CW pair in AT book(Am I correct in this idea?), so I want to use prop. 0.17 (to prove that the space $X \times I$ and $(X\times I) /(X \times \{0,1\})$ are homotopy equivalent and hence the unreduced suspension is a cw complex as required) but this Prop requires that $X\times \{0,1\}$ be  contractible in the CW pair $(X \times I,X \times \{0,1\}).$ what confuses me is that they are 2 separate compies of $X.$
Could anyone clarify this to me please?

It is not true that $X\times I$ and $(X\times I)/(X\times {0,1})$ are homotopy equivalent, and I'm not sure why you want to prove it.

Homotopy equivalence is not relevant here or in the linked question.

To answer the question in the title: as long as $X$ is nonempty, the space $X \times {0,1}$ is not path-connected, so it is not contractible.

@Emptymind To ensure that $(X \times I) / (X \times {0, 1})$ is a CW-complex, you want $X \times {0, 1}$ to be a subcomplex of $X \times I$. This has nothing to do with contractibility. As for the other question: They are, and this comes down to contractibility of a subcomplex of the unreduced suspension $SX$. Perhaps you're getting the two mixed up?
